# how will we use the output of an input statement , what will be used in place of (is)in the command and birthdayRun in a command

Tags: python, if-statement, input, output

```
occasionDay = input()
if occasionDay is 'Birthday':
    birthdayRun()
```

#what will be used in place of (is) birthdayRun is a command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `is` with `==` and it will match the string and if equals to it will run the `birthdayRun()`

```
occasionDay = input("Enter:") # you can put value you want to display for user
if occasionDay == 'Birthday':
   birthdayRun()
```